# MediaWiki: Parameters for external images

Tags: external, mediawiki, wiki

I'm trying to set some parameters (e.g. size, alignment) for external images on my MediaWiki.

I have both `$wgAllowExternalImages` and `$wgAllowImageTag` set to true, but it still doesn't work. Trying

```
[[Image:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Sega-Genesis-Model2-32X.jpg|50px]]
```

or

```
[[File:Sega-Genesis-Model2-32X.jpg|link=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0|caption]]
```

doesn't work.
Just displaying images, without setting any parameters, works by `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Sega-Genesis-Model2-32X.jpg`.

However, everything works with internal images.

Sources: [Help:Images - MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images)

Comment: External images cannot be resized, you will have to use css for this

Comment: What about alignment?

Comment: I believe alignment should work, but I'm not sure, why don't you just try and see?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is an image on Wikimedia Commons, which is not an external image but an image from a foreign repo. Just enable [InstantCommons](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/InstantCommons) (and make sure your thumbnailer is configured, of course).

```
$wgUseInstantCommons = true;
```

Then use the image as a local one:

```
[[Image:Sega-Genesis-Model2-32X.jpg|50px]]
```